# HTTP server in separate goroutine to display progress

Tags: http, go, goroutine

Let's say I have a long-running programme in Go that is being ran on a server and, from time to time, the user needs to view its results (stats). We of course can create a screen session and make him login by SSH, reattach to the session etc, but it doesn't seem practical.
As a better option, I want to launch some sort of embedded HTTP server which shall listen on some port like 8081 and, whenever requested, return the info in form of text (or JSON or XML or whatever).
Basically it should just compose a string and return it through HTTP/1.1.
It obviously should run in its own goroutin (in background). It is guarantied that the server receives low volume of traffic (e.g. no simultaneous requests)
So probably there's something ready-to-use?

Comment: Yes, there is. For example standard library [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

Comment: not to mention [`expvar`](https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/)

Comment: Don't think that this is useful. Have you heard about log files? Simply write a line on each status update after putting the process into background using the `&` operator. That would be a) What log files are good for. b) Not exposing an unnecessary security risk. c) WAY easier to implement, especially for a beginner.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I disagree with your statement. While logs are useful to collect a stream of events, aggregating and analyzing those events to present an equivalent result just displaces the problem. Also, running a long-running program as a job in a terminal is a very bad idea, since accidentally exiting the shell will kill the program. Better use a process manager such as supervisord. Finally, Go makes it extremely easy to embed an HTTP server in any program, it is a pretty common pattern, even in the standard library, as demonstrated with the aforementionned `expvar` package.

Comment: @SirDarius I really assume that we rather know what we are doing. Take a nohup, or whatever means. But the general problem that an open port leads to an increased security concern. Just because something is easy doesn't mean you _should_ do it. And log files for monitoring a progress are idiomatic. Not for Go, but for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This will require some cooperative programming with your long-running program to listen for requests. It's also the perfect use case for a `chan chan`

```
// inside your main package

// MakeResponse listens for a request for information and serves it back on
// request's channel.
func MakeResponse(request chan chan interface{}) {
    // I'm not sure what kind of raw data you're trying to throw back, but
    // you probably don't want to do your encoding to json here. Do that in
    // your webserver instead.

    for resp := range request {
        resp <- getInternalStateInformation()
    }
}
```

```
// inside your listener package

var requests chan chan interface{}

func init() {
    requests = make(chan chan interface{}, 10)
}

func RequestInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    response := make(chan interface{})
    requests<-response
    data := <-response
    outData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't marshal data %v\n", data)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, outData) // or more likely execute a template with this
                           // context
}

func main() {
    defer close(requests)
    go longrunningprog.MakeResponse(requests)
    http.HandleFunc("/", RequestInfo)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
}
```

Comment: Why have the extra `MakeResponse` goroutine with the channel of channels, when `RequestInfo` already executes in it's own goroutine, and you're synchronously waiting for the data anyway?

Comment: @JimB I assumed the listener would be in its own package and you wouldn't want to directly expose the data from the main long-running program to the outside world. Note that `MakeResponse` calls an unexported example function to get the state to pass.

Comment: Ah ok. Even so, IMO a simple mutex here would make the API more clear since this is just a synchronous function call hidden behind channels.

Comment: @JimB that's possible! I tend to overuse channels and ignore other sync methods completely in Go. YMMV, but I'm happy with the channel solution.

Comment: An interesting idea might be to use some asynchronous framework (AJAX? WebSockets?) to serve the data from requests on a different endpoint and have "/" just load a mostly-empty template (that fills on each packet from the WebSocket or from each AJAX request). I'm not sure that's exactly what OP is looking for, however.